# Forces on arbitrary surface from the shear tensor

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I'm doing CFD calculations using an Open source code. The code solves Navier-Stokes equations and I can get the velocity and pressure fields. From the velocity field I managed to reconstruct the shear stress tensor using Newton's law of viscosity.

Now I'm trying to evaluate the shear stress vector on a wall or a solid surface that immersed in the fluid using the known stress tensor such that the three vector components represents the tangential force (shear) per unit area and normal force per unit area.

I thought about Cauchy's Stress theorem, i.e. using:
    $$T_j=\sigma _{ij}n_i$$
But then I realized that (correct me if I'm wrong) the stress vector $T_j$ is in the normal direction so it has no tangential component to the surface.

So, any better idea?

Comment: No.  It gives all three components.  j can take on all three values from 1 to 3

Comment: Yes, it indeed gives 3 component. But, as far as I know, the direction of the magnitude of those 3 components (x, y, z) will be perpendicular to the surface, isn't it?

Comment: No way.  To get the normal component, you need to dot t with n (again).  Then you subtract this normal component (times n) from t to get the shear stress.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thanks, now it's clear. One last question: when we do the dot product sometimes I find people who use $\sigma.n$ (for example your reply [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250227/wall-shear-stress?rq=1)) and others use $n.\sigma$ (for example [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor)).  
I think to get the equation in the original post we should use $n.\sigma$. Is that right?

Comment: It doesn’t matter.  The stress tensor is symmetric.